# Can you export an entire page including label and text to excel not just table in javascript?

Tags: javascript

heres my function tables are being exported but not the labels. Labels are dynamic

```
function ExportToExcel(type, fn, dl) {
    var elt = document.getElementById("content");
    var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, { sheet: "sheet1" });
    return dl ?
      XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: type, bookSST: true, type: 'base64' }):
      XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || ('MySheetName.' + (type || 'xlsx')));
 }
```